# Synonimize [go] and [golang]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tag-synonyms

The [golang](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/golang) tag was just recently created. It seems there's already a [go](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/go) tag that serves the same purpose as [golang](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/golang).

Should [golang](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/golang) be made a synonym of [go](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/go)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just created the synonym.

Thanks! :-)